# jQuery plugin with its own API

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing my first jQuery plugin and I want to be able to do this:

```
var myPluginVar = $("someElement").myPlugin();

myPluginVar.customFunctionCallWithinPlugin();
```

Any idea how to go about it?

***EDIT***

Please visit http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#api to see what i mean

Comment: Note: it's == it is, its == of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this design with something similar to the following. I have wrapped the plugin definition within an anonymous function to keep `PluginObj` from polluting the global namespace.

```
(function($) {
    function PluginObj() {
        // construct stuff
    }

    PluginObj.prototype.customFunctionCallWithinPlugin = function() {
        // do stuff
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        return new PluginObj();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The jQuery method returns a new object with the methods you define. This is a non-standard design for a jQuery plugin though, so if you plan to distribute it make sure it is thoroughly documented.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to return an instance of the plugin rather than "this".

e.g.

```
(function(){
    // private constructor that is only accessable by your plugin.
    function _Plugin(elements, args){
        // do stuff
    }
    _Plugin.prototype.customFunctionCallWithinPlugin = function(){
        // do more stuff
    };
    $.fn.Plugin = function(args){
        return new _Plugin(this, args);
    };
})();
```

EDIT: Alex beat me to it.

Comment: The similarity of our comments is quite astounding. Have a +1 yourself :d